# Unable to Determine what causes VBA to fail when attempting to load a Form

Tags: winforms, vba, vb6, autocad, autocad-plugin

[Here](http://youtu.be/A0URVFPSoHs) is a full video explanation of the problem.

It begins by throwing up the Autocad Help for some reason.

Then Shows a message that says "Could not load an object because it is not available on this machine"

Then I get a message like this:

[image]

The first thing called by Autocad button is `showWallTypeManagementForm()`
Here is the Code that accompanies that Error Message in the Debugger:

```
Public Sub showWallTypeManagementForm()
    frmWallTypeManager.Show
End Sub
```

or as a screenshot.

[image]

here is the form (frmWallTypeManager) that it is attempting to show:

[image]

Comment: @jth41: An off-site video isn't really meaningful. It can't be seen here, it has no value for searching by future readers here, and if the off-site location is unavailable for some reason your question has no value. Please [edit] your question to explain the problem here clearly. We have no idea what `frmWallTypeManager` is, and don't have the ability to read your mind (or code) from where we are; if you want us to help you, you need to provide the specific details in your question so we can try to do so.

Comment: @KenWhite what else would be helpful in addition to the changes I have just made?

Comment: @jth41: An image of the form doesn't really help. It clearly uses a reference to something that isn't being included with your installation: "Could not load an object because **it is not available on this machine**". So what external references (ActiveX controls, third-party libraries, etc.) does your form use?

Comment: @KenWhite If you do watch the video. You notice that the references shown are identical to the ones in the working XP virtual Machine.

Comment: @JeremyLin: They clearly can't be *identical*, right? If they were, the error wouldn't be happening. There is *something different*.

Comment: VB6 seems to use CoCreateInstanceEx. Any way put a breakpoint on bp ole32!CoCreateInstanceEx, bp OLE32!CoCreateInstance, and bp OLE32!CoGetClassObject. You can use NTSD (type it and see how to set symbol path) or WinDbg (Install theWindows SDK but just choose the debugging tools. Create a folder called Symbols in C:\ Start Windbg. File menu - Symbol File Path and enter srv*C:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols Close and reopen WinDbg. Put breakpoints in. Run till you get the right one. And see what code this function returns.

Comment: Are you using a 32bit or 64bit OS?

Comment: I am using 64Bit (Windows 8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your video, you are attempting to use a 32bit DAO.DLL with a 64bit OS. It is unfortunate but that is one of the DLL's that just cannot be used with 64bit Autocad. From the looks of your form, you are probably getting some information from a database with DAO. This will cause your errors.